# Display calculate value in new column of grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

Working with gridview in asp.net,
   I am displaying data in gridview from database, but i had 2 columns grossamount and deductionamount

Need pass sum of both the value and subtract
 ex:sum(gross)-sum(deduction) = sub amount and also should take based on type if type ="g"

gross data should sum  and vice versa dispaly
ex:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="13%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <HeaderTemplate>
      Amount
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PayeeAmount")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="item_Style1" />
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" Enabled="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PayeeAmount")%>'
                        CssClass="black_normal" Width="180px" Wrap="true" TextMode="SingleLine" MaxLength="20"
                        ValidationGroup="GSave"></asp:TextBox>
                    <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fltrDescriptionPayeeDeductionmount" runat="server"
                        FilterType="Custom" FilterMode="InvalidChars" InvalidChars="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@!#$%^&*%<> ,"
                        TargetControlID="txtPayeeDeductionAmount">
                    </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Calculate this values grossamount - deductionamount= subtract amount.

This subtraction amount column is not in database. How to customize column and display data in  grid view column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your query and create a column which has the required data and bind it to grid.

You can create a template field as following

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="13%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
   <HeaderTemplate>
         Amount
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Int32.Parse(Eval("grossamount").ToString())-Int32.Parse(Eval("deductionamount").ToString())%>'>
    </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

if your data is `Int32` or cast to some other type as you require.

Comment: sorry , i cannot do anything in database, i need to add column in grid view ,how?

Comment: @Shekhar: +1 typecast will be needed

Comment: @naveen I was updating my answer.

Comment: hi , how to display sum of gross and sum of deduction ,                        both the values in same column, based on type i need subtract value now how can i pass "(Eval("grossamount").ToString())-Int32.Parse(Eval("deductionamount").ToString() AS SubtractAmount

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Calculation(TWD, AWD, THD, TTL, TOTALHOLIDAYS) {
        var TWD = $(document.getElementById(TWD)).html();
        var AWD = $(document.getElementById(AWD)).val();
        var THD =$( document.getElementById(THD)).val();
        var TotalHolidays = TOTALHOLIDAYS;

        var TotalTakenLeave = (parseInt( TWD) + parseInt(TotalHolidays)) - (parseInt(THD) +parseInt( AWD))

        $('#' + TTL).html( TotalTakenLeave);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Calculation(TWD, AWD, THD, TTL, TOTALHOLIDAYS) {
    var TWD = $(document.getElementById(TWD)).html();
    var AWD = $(document.getElementById(AWD)).val();
    var THD =$( document.getElementById(THD)).val();
    var TotalHolidays = TOTALHOLIDAYS;

    var TotalTakenLeave = (parseInt( TWD) + parseInt(TotalHolidays)) - (parseInt(THD) +parseInt( AWD))

    $('#' + TTL).html( TotalTakenLeave);
}
```